# Permission Denial on SEND action intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo

This is the log, I am receving on crash in Samsung running Oero OS:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:
>   starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain
>   flg=0x80001 pkg=com.google.android.apps.maps
>   cmp=com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.apps.gmm.sharing.SendTextToClipboardActivity
>   clip={text/plain T:"XYZ"

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
            share.setPackage(packageName);
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your code that is triggering this crash?

Comment: Please check added my code

Comment: Unfortunately, `queryIntentActivities()` and similar `PackageManager` methods do not filter out those for which you lack permissions to start. Apparently, `com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.apps.gmm.sharing.SendTextToClipboardActivity` supports `ACTION_SEND`, but not from your app.

Comment: so what's the solution, for this problem

Comment: There is none, other than to not try using `ACTION_SEND` with an arbitrary `ComponentName`.

Comment: I didn't get it, my code is working for all the devices other than this only Samsung Galaxy S9 with 8.0 operating system. It create crash when copy to clipboard option pressed chosen by the list of action send. I need that option copy to clipboard. Please suggest

Comment: "my code is working for all the devices" -- there are 26,000 Android device models. I doubt that you have tested all of them. "I need that option copy to clipboard" -- remove the `setComponent()` call.

Comment: I'm seeing this crash as well, and it just started spiking in frequency on Aug 26. I noticed "com.google.android.apps.maps" and thought this might be related to Google Maps. So I updated Maps on my device, and now I see two different "Copy to clipboard" choices in my share sheet! If I choose the one that I usually use, it works fine. If I select the new one, added by Google Maps, I get this crash. The fact that Google Maps is responding to a generic "text/plain" intent with its own "Copy to clipboard" handler seems like a Google Maps bug to me.

Comment: My guess: Android Q doesn't provide a native "Clipboard" option as a share target (they moved that to the top, as a separate button). Since Google Maps uses its own implementation for the share dialog, they now had to add their own "Copy to clipboard" option for Q. This in turn probably led to a bug where that option 'leaks' into other share dialogs, too.

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of options here. You can avoid this crash by specifically filtering out the `SendTextToClipboardActivity` that Google Maps recently added as an intent-handler. (It looks *exactly* like the genuine Android "Copy to clipboard" share-target, and is most likely the result of a bug on the part of Google Maps.) Or you can filter out any `ResolveInfo` where the corresponding `Activity` is not exported; however, this could result in *also* filtering out share-targets within your own app that you *do* want to show to the user, in which case you would need to allow non-exported Activities from your own app package.

For example, suppose you have something like this to obtain a list of providers for your `ACTION_SEND` intent:

```
PackageManager packageManager = mActivity.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> providers = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
```

You could then filter out providers that are known to cause problems, and/or providers for which the Activity isn't marked as exported. For example, you could use a check such as the following to build your own list of providers to be displayed to the user:

```
for (ResolveInfo provider : providers) {
    if ("com.google.android.apps.maps".equalsIgnoreCase(provider.activityInfo.packageName)
            && "com.google.android.apps.gmm.sharing.SendTextToClipboardActivity".equalsIgnoreCase(provider.activityInfo.name)) {
        continue; // Skip specific Activity you don't want to show
    }
    if (!BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.equalsIgnoreCase(provider.activityInfo.packageName) && !provider.activityInfo.exported) {
        continue; // Skip providers where the Activity is not marked with exported=true, unless they're from our own app
    }
    acceptableProviders.add(provider);
}
```

How to then go about displaying the `acceptableProviders` as share options is left as an exercise to the reader. The key is filtering out known bad providers.

Meanwhile, you can also contact Google to complain about the bad behavior of this new intent-handler, which is essentially masquerading as the trusted Android `text/plain` handler used for the "Copy to clipboard" share-target.